# EXCEL FORMULA FOR DATES

Tags: excel-formula

I just want to ask an excel formula for this.

If an employee exceeds one year of employment he will have a free uniform

If he was hired last October 1, 2015 and he requests for new uniform this October 22, 2016 then he should have free uniform.

10/1/2015 - 10/22/2016 =  "Can Avail Free Uniform" or "Cannot Avail!"

I just want the two optional answers to reflect using an excel formula.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If I would create a formula like this:

I would use 4 cell columns:
Date Hired,Date Request,Years of Service,isAvail

On my Years of Service, I would use `DateDif` Function,
Where `=(DateDif('cella','cellb',"m")/12)` in order to achieve a year.
Then on isAvail column, I will use `=IIF('cellc >= 1', "Can Avail","Cannot Avail")`

See if it helps.

Comment: If it helps you. Mark this as an answer. Your welcome

Comment: @gnMercadoWhat if the availment is only once in every succeeding year

Comment: What if the availment is only once in every succeeding year. What would be my formula?

Comment: Then count the total availment of that employee. Then check if he/she avails more than once. You could do something like flag or remarks on your excel.

Comment: What if the availment is only once in every succeeding year. What would be my formula? For Example the employee requests for another free uniform on February 25, 2017 he should not get the free uniform since it can only be availed once in succeeding year. Since his hiring date is 10/1/2015 he cannot avail because he needs to be with the company for another 1  year which is on 10/1/2017.

Comment: @GN Mercado What if the availment is only once in every succeeding year. What would be my formula? For Example the employee requests for another free uniform on February 25, 2017 he should not get the free uniform since it can only be availed once in succeeding year. Since his hiring date is 10/1/2015 he cannot avail because he needs to be with the company for another 1 year which is on 10/1/2017.

Comment: A workaround here without using programming will need you to use a history and present worksheet style here. After a year you should move your present excel sheet into history. Then use `VLOOKUP` and `IIF` function in order to check if he/she availed a uniform based from history worksheet

Comment: Ok.. would you mine if you could give me a sample transaction for this. Thank you so much s

Comment: Create a 'Remarks' excel column. pattern it to my isAvail Column formula. Then if the isAvail column sets to 'Can Avail' set your remarks to 'Availed' as well. Then move it to history sheet. Once the employee tries to order another uniform. Check the history sheet using 'VLOOKUP' function. If the remarks on the history sheet is 'Availed', mark the request as 'Disapproved' or something that can validate the request. It's up to you

Answer (score 1):

I would use these four columns

[image]

and use the following formula in D2:

```
=IF(AND((C2-A2)/365>=1,(C2-B2)/365>=1),"Can avail free uniform","Cannot avail")
```

This checks to see of the time since date of hire AND the time since the previous request is more than 1 year and returns "Can avail free uniform" if both equals ore are greater than 1, and returns "Cannot avail" if one of them is less than 1.